# How to detect mod_rewrite without apache_get_modules()?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to detect `mod_rewrite` in PHP when function `apache_get_modules()` is not available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could analyze the output of `phpinfo()`:

```
ob_start();
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
var_dump(strpos($contents, 'mod_rewrite') !== false);
```

Comment: Wow, nice one, I wouldn't have thought of that. btw. You could use ob_get_clean() function.

Comment: But `ob_get_clean` doesn’t end the buffer so you would need another `ob_end_*` call anyway.

Comment: It actually does. In documentation is: ob_get_clean() essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean().

Comment: As a note, this doesn't appear to work when PHP is run FCGI.  Not seeing anything as far as apache modules go in INFO_MODULES.